# IBM MQ 7.1 RC 2035 MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED

Tags: security, ibm-mq, mq

Now I am working on the IBM MQ 7.1 and this MQ has been installed into a Sun Solaris Server. All machine are unix OS.

I have another two application server also Sun Solaris and both are running on different machine.

AppServerA now is completely successfully connect to the MQ server with the ID as below :

```
 AppServerA
    group - app:54323
    id - mgr:200:54323
```

AppServerB now is failed to connect to the MQ server with the reason code 2035 and with ID as below :

```
AppServerB
    group - uat:54324
    id - uat:200:54324
```

MQ server priviledges as below :

```
group - mqm:54323
id - mqm:200
```

Primarily, I am suspecting that group ID is not same with the MQ server so that caused AppServerB cannot connect to MQ server.
But now I have reset the AppServerB login credentials to as below :

```
AppServerB
    group - app:54323
    id - uat:201:54323
```

After reset ID , it still failed to connect. Any idea ?

**Last time worked on AIX server, this method was working fine when I faced the same issue.

Comment: so are you using different user/group names but the ids are same across the servers? say group app:54323 is in appserver B while mqserver has mqm:54323. Did you refresh or get new sessions. Is there a CHLAUTH blocking a specific IP address?

Comment: this is totally weird. I have read the MQ 7.1 support docment, the security features is enhanced. My way to solve to the problem is add in this login info when my java program connect to MQ while AppServerA does not need this login info but can connect to MQ successfully.
MQEnvironment.userID="mqm";
MQEnvironment.password="mqm2013";

Comment: The thing is mq never validates your password. You will need a security exit, if you want to login/validate with password. Connecting as mqm/admin is problematic when you have mq 7.1 above. Did you try with CHLAUTH(DISABLED)?  If you have it enabled, you need to allow admin as found in http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.doc%2Fmi77190_.htm

Comment: Yes, I have disabled it when I create the queue.

Answer (score 2):

The queue manager error log will show the reason why you were given a 2035. The error will list the user ID in question and the problem with that user ID which caused the 2035:

For example, lack of `+put` authority or banned by CHLAUTH, et cetera.